# Google Maps Show Nearest Database Markers to My Location

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to develope something where a user types in their postcode or part of their address and they are then shown markers that are near to them.

I have all my markers stored in a database. My original idea was to bring back results from MySQL that were in a given range.

E.g. if my lat/long is 1.500 by 2.100 then all results in the database brings back rows that are lat 1.500 +/- 0.05 AND long 2.100 +/- 0.05.

This would work but I want to know if something already exists in the Google Maps API that can do this or do it better than my idea?

Comment: Yeah! Why the down vote? Some people...

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar and I put my code on GitHub.  This is a (far from complete) app that demonstrates how to use your current location (using GeoLocation) and then looking up markers on Google Maps.  Hope this helps you!

https://github.com/RichBuff/TexasHistoricalMarkers

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I am doing it for now until I find a better way. It is very likely that performance will begin to suffer when more and more rows are added.

**PHP/SQL**

```
public function getMapNodes($lat, $long) {
    $SQL = 'SELECT users.id AS usersId, screenName, lat, lng,
            COALESCE(flagSrc, 0) AS flag, src
            FROM users_locations, users
            LEFT JOIN users_prefs ON users_prefs.userId = users.id
            LEFT JOIN users_images ON users_images.userId = users.id
                LEFT JOIN languages ON users_prefs.languageId = languages.id
            WHERE users.id = users_locations.userId
            AND (? < (lat+0.2) AND ? > (lat-0.2))
            AND (? < (lng+0.3) AND ? > (lng-0.3))';
    $r = $this->db->prepare($SQL);
    $r->execute(array($lat, $lat, $long, $long));
    return $r->fetchAll();
}
```

If performance does start to suffer, a Memcache implementation would be a nice silver bullet.